# Can I delete the earlier Windows 11 ISO file from Media Creation Tool and directly replace it with the ISO file for 22H2?

Tags: iso-image, windows-11, windows-installation, media-creation-tool

I found a site that directly downloaded the ISO for 22H2 to my C Drive.  I currently have the earlier version of Windows 11 installed.  As I may not run it like an exe file in order to install it, can I remove from the Media Creation tool used for the earlier installation, the earlier ISO file and just copy the downloaded ISO file to it, then use the MCT to install the new version?  And won't use of the MCT remove my 3rd party software, even if I used it to download the new Windows 11 version?

Comment: "I currently have the earlier version of Windows 11 installed." - What version exactly?  "Can I remove from the Media Creation tool" - You could have done this after you initially upgraded to Windows 11.  You could also just download the Windows 11 22H2 MCT and replace the version you have.  However, you shouldn't be using the MCT to upgrade to Windows 11 22H2 you should be using Windows Update by simply clicking `Download and install`

Comment: FYI, you can extract the contents of the iso file using 7-Zip and then run the setup exe. @Don a

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to download another ISO file.

The 22H2 upgrade is very easy. I did it yesterday on two machines.

It comes in two parts and order does not matter:

(A) There is a .NET Framework update that must be done followed by a mandatory restart.

(B) Then there is the "cumulative-like" 22H2 upgrade followed by another mandatory restart.

It does not matter about the order of A and B. I did A then B on my laptop and I did B then A on my Desktop (that is the way it was offered).

Much easier just to update than to do it via the media creation link ISO file.

**Footnote:**  there is nothing dramatically new in 22H2 - just like a cumulative update. No Windows.old if you were fully up to date just prior.

Comment: 22H2 isn't a cumulative update it's a feature update. Upgrade Assistant can be used or manually seeking 22H2 through [Windows Update](https://wccftech.com/how-to-skip-the-line-and-manually-install-windows-11-22h2/) and clicking `Download and install`.

Comment: Yes . But 22H2 is so simple and so fast to install that there is no need to use the Upgrade Assistant to install it. Of course you can - just no real need

Comment: I did edit my answer to make the “cumulative “ language as “like” a cumulative update .  It shows up in update history as cumulative

Comment: Contrary to what I believe to be the case, Windows 11 22H2 can be delivered through an enablement package.  It's still not like cumulative update, since it cannot be downloaded through the WU Catalog, and can **only** be received through Windows Update.